# Web Framework Built for Recommendations

Tags: predictive-modeling, data-cleaning

I'm wondering if there is a web framework well suited for placing recommendations on content.

In most cases, a data scientist goes through after the fact and builds (or uses) a completely different tool to create recommendations. This involves analyzing traffic logs, a history of shopping cart data, ratings, and so forth. It usually comes from multiples sources (the web server, the application's database, Google Analytics, etc) and then has to be cleaned up and processed, THEN delivered back to the application in way it understands.

Is there a web framework on the market which handles collecting this data up front, as to minimize the retrospective data wrangling?

Comment: http://prediction.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen anything like that and very much doubt that such frameworks exist, at least, as complete frameworks. The reason for this is IMHO the fact that data *transformation* and *cleaning* is very **domain-** and **project-specific**. Having said that, there are multiple tools that can help with these activities in terms of *partial automation* and *integration* with and between existing statistical and Web frameworks.

For example, for **Python**, the use of *data manipulation* library `pandas` as well as *machine learning* library `scikit-learn` can be easily integrated with Web frameworks (especially Python-based, but not necessarily), as these libraries are also Python-based. These and other Python data science tools that might be of interest can be found here: http://pydata.org/downloads. Specifically, for cleaning and pre-processing tasks, which you asked about, `pandas` seem to be the first tool to explore. Again, for Python, the following discussion on StackOverflow on methods and approaches might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14262433/2872891.

Consider an example of **another platform**. The use of `pandas` for data transformation and cleaning is rather *low-level*. The platform that I like very much and currently use as the platform of choice for data science tasks is `R`. Rich *ecosystem of R packages* especially shines in the area of data transformation and cleaning. This is because, in addition to very flexible low-level methods of performing these tasks, there are some R packages, which take a *higher-level approach* to the problem, which may potentially improve developer's productivity and decrease the amount of defects. In particular, I'm talking about two packages, which I find very promising: `editrules` and `deducorrect`. You can find more detailed information about these and other R packages for data transformation and cleaning in my another answer here on *Data Science StackExchange* (paper that I reference in the last link there could be especially useful, as it presents an *approach* to data transformation and cleaning that is *generic* enough, so that could be used as a **framework** for this on any decent platform): https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/722/2452.

**UPDATE**: On the topic of *recommender systems* and their integration with data wrangling tools and Web frameworks, you may find my other answer here on DS SE useful: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/836/2452.